# Wait an event in JAVA

Tags: java

I am new in java. 
I try to make a program and I have a question.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class AccessFIleTest 
{//start of class AccessFIleTest 
//variables here


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {//start of main method
        String pinakas[]=new String[3];
        ReturnSQLConnectionOptions newOptions= new ReturnSQLConnectionOptions();

         pinakas=newOptions.getPinakastimon();        
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pinakas));



    }//end of main method

}//end of class AccessFIleTest
```

So  the newOptions checks if a spesific file exists! If it does then it reads the contents and put them in the array pinakas and everythig works great.
If not it shows a jframe window that the user has to put the values, then stores the file and also returns on the getPinakastimon() the values the user insert.
The problem is that this code here even the window that waits the values is visible and waiting data from user procedds to print the pinakas array that ofcourse is empty till that moment.
Any help?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The simplest (but not the best) option is to show a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JDialog instead, this should show you how to setup one to accept a user entered String http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your correctly I believe that you want to run this code as an action connected to some button on your window.

In this case put this code to separate method, create button (or probably you already have one), then add action listener to this button and implement it: just call the code that saves data to disk.

I hope this helps. If you need more concrete help please post more code snippets.

Comment: Well the code works fine when the file dont exist and creates the file with the value that the user inmput. The problem is that the pinakas is empty for first use and so the System.out.print prints me null.